# Configure Visual Studio 2013 to use TFS and not GIT

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

I have been using TFS quite happily the last few months, and all of a sudden my project is now using GIT.

I think it was after I installed the Eclips TFS plugin for android development. 
How can I change it back to use TFS as my source control.
When I click on Team Explorer now it is git.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC see Tools / Options / Version control and select the default version control plugin.